# Binance {code: -1022, msg: 'Signature for this request is not valid.'}

Tags: api-key, binance

I use SSR in next js with simple js fetch to make binance order, but facing with {code: -1022, msg: 'Signature for this request is not valid.'}

```
var keysBuy = {
    "APIkey": 'my api key',
    "SECRETkey": 'my a secret key'
}
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("X-MBX-APIKEY", keysBuy['APIkey']);
var dataQueryString = `recvWindow=20000&timestamp=${Date.now()}`;

var signature = crypto.createHmac('sha256', keysBuy['SECRETkey']).update(dataQueryString).digest('hex')
var cryptoQueryString = `symbol=FIROUSDT&side=BUY&type=MARKET&quantity=5`
var requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: myHeaders,
    redirect: 'follow',
};
const orderBuy = await fetch(`https://api.binance.com/api/v3/order?${cryptoQueryString}&${dataQueryString}&signature=${signature}`, requestOptions)
const orderData = await orderBuy.json()
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to join dataQueryString and cryptoQueryString

var dataQueryString = `symbol=FIROUSDT&side=BUY&type=MARKET&quantity=5&timestamp=${Date.now()}`;